# Loading external Templates

Tags: angular

I got the following problem:

I have to load external Templates into my Angular App

The Urls for those Templates are stored in the Database

There is one template URL for:

- The Header
- The Body (contains the Content div)
- The Footer

The Body Template contains a

```html
<div id="content"></div>
```

Into this div with the Id, my Apps Angular Content should be loaded.

My Current approach:

In my AppComponent onInit I am loading the Urls from the DB and retrieve those via another http GET call
I am showing a spinner until everything is loaded.

The only thing I found about loading external templates was `[innerHTML]` together with DomSanitizers `bypassSecurity` to load the templates and then in my Component use the Id Selector

```html
<html>
  <ng-container [innerHTML]='header | safeHtml'>
  <ng-container [innerHTML]='body | safeHtml'>
  <ng-container [innerHTML]='footer | safeHtml'>
</html>
```

And then my Component would insert its content via the Id Selector

```js
@Component({ selector: '[id=content]', })
```

This is kind of working but as you can imagine, not very performant and probably not the best approach. Also the selector is not working, my component is not inside the div from the template

Is there any other approach to accomplish this scenario?

Currently an index.jsp is used to import those templates now another Idea was to change the index.html in my angular.json to a separate index.jsp for the building part to make things easier, but the problem is then everything is missing while developing, because webpack cant handle the .jsp file.

Comment: Are there any reasons you want to load templates in such a complicated and insecure way?

Comment: Well it is currenlty done this way and the templates are provided by an external firm, now after switching to angular we are trying to port this approach. The reason is those templates are being themed by said firm and are imported by many different applications. Since the Header also includes styles the App can be  remotely changed.Currenlty the index.jsp is just importing the templates which works flawlessly, this should be working with angular too

Answer (score 0):

The only possible way I can think of is you will have to use [ng-template](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives). You can switch the templates based upon the different responses backend sends or just create different components that is way better

```
<ng-template [ngIf]="hero">
  <div class="name">{{hero.name}}</div>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: Hey Thanks for your answer do you have an example on how this is done using <ng-template> ? And any idea how i get the selector inside the backend response string working?

Answer (score 0):

After a few days of digging, i finally found a working solution.

Basically I am loading the templates via http.get, adding the remote Head to mine and generating a new dynamic component at runtime with the body.

Now that it works, I will rest create a Service that is getting the urls from the DB and return me the template strings so I only need to do 1 request, which I can move to a service.

There is one small issue, the styles and scripts that come with the remote head take time to load after adding to the main head, so I had to show the spinner to avoid unstlyed elements.

```
export class AppComponent {

    @ViewChild('container', {read: ViewContainerRef, static: false})
        container: ViewContainerRef;
        private componentRef: ComponentRef<{}>;

        constructor(private httpStatus: HTTPStatus,
                          private spinner: NgxSpinnerService,
                          private http: HttpClient,
                          private injectorService: InjectorService) {

        spinner.show();

        http.get('https://somedomain.com/header.php', {responseType: 'text'}).subscribe((header: string) => {
               this.injectorService.injectHeader(header);
        }, error => {
                console.log('error loading header');
        }, () =>  {
                http.get('https://somedomain.com/body.html', {responseType: 'text'}).subscribe((body: string) => {
                    this.injectorService.compileTemplate(this.componentRef, this.container, body);
                });
            });
        }
    }
```

app.component.html

```
 <div #container></div>
```

injector.service.ts

```
    @Injectable()
    export class InjectorService {


    constructor(private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
                private compiler: Compiler) {}

    public injectHeader(includes: string): void {
        let head = document.head.innerHTML;
        head = head.concat(includes);
        document.head.innerHTML = head;
    }

    public compileTemplate(componentRef: ComponentRef<{}>, container: ViewContainerRef, html: string) {
        const metadata = {
            selector: 'runtime-sample',
            template: html
        };

        const factory = this.createComponentFactorySync(this.compiler, metadata, DynamicComponent);

        if (componentRef) {
            componentRef.destroy();
            componentRef = null;
        }

        componentRef = container.createComponent(factory);

    }

    private createComponentFactorySync(compiler: Compiler, metadata: Component, componentClass: any): ComponentFactory<any> {
        const cmpClass = componentClass || DynamicComponent;
        const decoratedCmp = Component(metadata)(cmpClass);
        @NgModule({ imports: [CommonModule, FormsModule], declarations: [ContentComponent, FilterPipe, decoratedCmp] })
        class RuntimeComponentModule { }

        const module: ModuleWithComponentFactories<any> = compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsSync(RuntimeComponentModule);
        return module.componentFactories.find(f => f.componentType === decoratedCmp);
    }
}
```

Since the body I have loaded contains a

```
<div id="content">
```

In my ContentComponent I can use

```
selector: '[id=content]'
```

To load my Angular App into the remote Body